# How to play MPEG-TS (transport stream) from WPF and Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, video-streaming, mediaelement, mpeg

I've tried MediaElement with a .ts file - its not interested (HRESULT: 0xC00D11B1).

The TS file plays with WMP no problems (Cannot seem to play it in graphedt though?)

I thought MediaElement was supposed to support what WMP supported?

Update: This is on Windows 7 by the way (apparently it has a slightly different media stack if that makes a difference, WMF etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPFMediaKit does work but you need to install a MPEG-TS "source filter" to allow DirectShow to read from the transport stream container.

I used [TSFileSource](https://github.com/natevoci/TSFileSource).

Also be careful on x64 vs x86... so far I have only managed to get it working when using all x86 components.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremiah Morrill is your man - http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com.

This will not work in SL but will definitely play them on WPF proper.

Comment: i've downloaded the WMK but from a quick poke around (i.e. trying to play a .TS file in the supplied application) it does not appear to support TS... I will delve further in

Comment: Does compiling your app as x86 make a difference?

Comment: @jeremiah totally out of context, but yes I eventually got around to testing WMK (after installing TSFileSource) and yes I did have problems getting it to display any video (worked fine at design time!). After reading your comment here I change to x86 and it works...